# Add padding to the left of radio button drawable

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I am trying to add padding to the left of radio button. But the padding is actually added between the drawable and text.

What i get: Space between drawable and text
[image]

What i want: Space to the left of drawable
[image]

My method for creating radio button:

```
private RadioButton createRadioButton(String text) {
    RadioButton btn = new RadioButton(requireContext());

    btn.setId(View.generateViewId());
    btn.setText(text);
    btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
    btn.setTextColor(answerButtonColor);
    btn.setButtonTintList(answerButtonColor);

    int pxHorizontal = Utils.convertDpToPx(requireContext(), 24);
    int pxVertical = Utils.convertDpToPx(requireContext(), 16);
    btn.setPadding(pxHorizontal, pxVertical, pxHorizontal, pxVertical);

    btn.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ));

    return btn;
}
```

Is there a way how to add padding to the left of the radio button?

Comment: You can make a layout with a MaterialRadioButton in it and then add that layout in your code. In this way, you can style your radio button as you wish. Is it suits your work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadioButton is a subclass of CompundButton, so we get drawable on the compound button and add inset to it.

```
val compoundButtonDrawable = CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(radioButton1)
val insetDrawable = InsetDrawable(compoundButtonDrawable, 32, 0, 0, 0)
radioButton1.buttonDrawable = insetDrawable
```

Comment: This will solve the problem with spacing, however it will cause background color not to be displayed all the way at the start of radio button.

Comment: @22LHS set background color on your RadioGroup instead of RadioButton

Comment: this solution is not suitable for what i need to achieve, because some of the radio buttons will be "highlighted" later based on other criteria. Solution you are proposing does not allow for setting different background on individual radio buttons.

Comment: Adding insets in particular API versions can break default animations of the compound buttons. Look example here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72772473/android-emulator-checkbox-and-radio-button-bug-various-incorrect-states-are-sh

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the radio button and I wrapped the whole radio button in an additional frame layout and added there extra padding. Unfortunately, it's breaking RadioGroup functionality(because you don't have RadioButton direct child) and you need to implement it by yourself by unselecting previous radio buttons after selecting a new one, but it's not too complex.